# Get first empty row index in a column in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am adding values in a column in google sheet, and I want to return the index of the first empty row. Is it possible with some formula?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
=match(TRUE,arrayformula(isblank(A:A)),0)
```